# Limit of infinite power tower $\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{a_0^{a_1^{a_2^{^{.^{.^{a_{n}}}}}}}}{b_0^{b_1^{b_2^{^{.^{.^{b_{n}}}}}}}}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

Let $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of natural numbers. Let us define a function which roughly "make a tower of powers out of $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$", i.e.
$$F:\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \cup \{+\infty\}$$
with
$$F(\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})=a_0^{a_1^{a_2^{.^{.^{.}}}}}$$
where the associativity is from the right (indeed $F$ has to be defined technically as a limit, which can be $+\infty$ of course).
Clearly if for some $n$ we have $a_n=0$ or $a_n=1$ then $F(\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})$ is finite.

Now let us define an equivalence relation $\sim_{inf}$ on $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ setting $$\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sim \{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \iff \liminf_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{a_0^{a_1^{a_2^{^{.^{.^{a_{n}}}}}}}}{b_0^{b_1^{b_2^{^{.^{.^{b_{n}}}}}}}} :=\frac{F(\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})}{F(\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})} \: \text{is finite and non zero}$$

Similarly let us define the equivalence relation $\sim_{sup}$ setting
$$\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sim \{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \iff \limsup_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{a_0^{a_1^{a_2^{^{.^{.^{a_{n}}}}}}}}{b_0^{b_1^{b_2^{^{.^{.^{b_{n}}}}}}}} :=\frac{F(\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})}{F(\{b_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}})} \: \text{is finite and non zero}$$

My question now is the following: does there exist a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $a_n \neq 0,1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that an equivalence class for $\sim_{inf}$ or $\sim_{sup}$ has more than $1$ element, i.e. $|[\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}]_{\sim_{inf}}| \geq 2$ or $|[\{a_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}]_{\sim_{sup}}| \geq 2$?

Comment: Since existence of limit is a rather strong requirement, which seems not very intuitive in this context, does finetness of $\limsup$ or $\liminf$ suffice?

Comment: @DieterKadelka yes it is also fine asking for limsup or liminf, I'll edit the question!

Comment: Your $\sim_{sup}$ and $\sim_{inf}$ are not equivalence relations (in fact, $\sim_{inf}$ is the opposite relation of $\sim_{sup}$). Instead what you probably want to do is assume that $\sim_{sup}$ *and* $\sim_{inf}$ are finite *and nonzero*

Comment: @Wojowu yeah sure, I'll fix it, thank you!